# Merge different HTTP calls which are dependent on each other in RxJS/Angular 6

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've been trying to find this answer for a while now, but I, as a new person to RxJS and Angular (2+), am looking for a way to combine the results of two HTTP GET calls. Once one call has finished, a new call has to be done based on that result. The result of the first call will be combined with the second call. Preferably in a property which has an object as type.

I have been playing with `mergeMap`, `switchMap` and `concatMap`. According to the documentation and guides these functions should do what I want to achieve. But How?

In my example I have got an ID (3 for example). This is my code:

```
this.postsService.getPostData(postId)
.switchMap(
  postData => Observable.forkJoin(this.getUserByPostData(postData))
)
.subscribe( result => console.log(result) );
```

*Both functions (`getPostData` and `getUserByPostData`) will return Observables due to `http.get`*

In this case, especially due to `forkJoin`, I'd expect my result to be merged. However, the result which I retrieve has been completely replaced with the result of the second request (which is the one inside the switchMap function).

How would I be able to combine the results? Would it also be possible to push the results of the second HTTP request (`this.getUserByPostData`) as a property of the results of the first request?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If the second request depends upon data in the response from first request and if you want to combine the two responses, you can use a `map` operator within the `switchMap`:

```ts
this.postsService.getPostData(postId).switchMap(
  postData => this.getUserByPostData(postData).map(
    userByPostData => ({ postData, userByPostData })
  )
).subscribe(({ postData, userByPostData })=> console.log(postData, userByPostData));
```

Also, if the observable returned by the `getPostData` is HTTP-based, it will only ever emit once, so there will never be any need to switch. You could just use `mergeMap`, instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not specific to Angular, but I solved it from the RxJs point of view.

My use case was to get the token from a service and use that token in the header to call another service . The solution I wanted would fit multiple chained calls.

We will have two approach slightly diff from each other .

case 1 :

If you have a trigger/start service

```js
const { forkJoin, of } = rxjs;
const { concatMap, delay, mergeMap, tap, map } = rxjs.operators;
function getAccessToken() {
  return of(`AccessToken`);
}
function getHTTP2Request(url2, reqOption) {
  console.log('reqOption received : ' + JSON.stringify(reqOption));
  return of(`Response from ${url2}`).pipe(delay(2000));
}
getAccessToken()
  .pipe(
    map((d) => {
      console.log('response in pipe', d);
      return d;
    })
  )
  .pipe(
    tap((val) => console.log(`BEFORE MAP: ${val}`)),
    map((accessToken) => {
      const requestOptions = {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
      };
      return requestOptions;
    }),
    tap((val) => console.log(`AFTER MAP: ${val}`))
  )
  .pipe(
    concatMap((requestOptions) => {
      console.log(
        'Second : requestOptions is ' + JSON.stringify(requestOptions)
      );
      return getHTTP2Request('url 2 ', requestOptions).pipe(
        map((d) => {
          console.log('response in pipe', d);
          return d;
        })
      );
    })
  )
  .pipe(tap((val) => console.log(`AFTER All: ${JSON.stringify(val)}`)))
  .subscribe((response) => console.log('Final : ' + response));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

case 2 :

Either you do not have a trigger point or , you want the process to be carried over multiple input

```js
const { forkJoin, of } = rxjs;
const { concatMap, delay, mergeMap, tap, map } = rxjs.operators;
function getAccessToken() {
  return of(`AccessToken`);
}
function getHTTP2Request(url2, reqOption) {
  console.log('reqOption received : ' + JSON.stringify(reqOption));
  return of(`Response from ${url2}`).pipe(delay(2000));
}
of('url1','url2')
  .pipe(
    concatMap((url) => {
      console.log('first : Sending request to ' + url);
      return getAccessToken().pipe(
        map((d) => {
          console.log('response in pipe', d);
          return d;
        })
      );
    }),
    tap((val) => console.log(`BEFORE MAP: ${val}`)),
    map((accessToken) => {
      const requestOptions = {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
      };
      return requestOptions;
    }),
    tap((val) => console.log(`AFTER MAP:`,val))
  )
  .pipe(
    concatMap((requestOptions) => {
      console.log(
        'Second : requestOptions is ' + JSON.stringify(requestOptions)
      );
      return getHTTP2Request('url 2 ', requestOptions).pipe(
        map((d) => {
          console.log('response in pipe', d);
          return d;
        })
      );
    })
  )
  .pipe(tap((val) => console.log(`AFTER All: ${val}`)))
  .subscribe((response) => console.log('Final : ' + response));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

This structure can be piped over and over again depending on the requirement.